# Get address from parametr and bind it

Tags: c, sockets, parameters

Im trying to get address from parameter and later if some address was there, pass to `bind()`. I created some code but I still can't get address from parameter to variable `adresa`.

even `printf("Zadana adresa %s\n", adresa);` don't print anything.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
char adresa[255];

void checkParameters(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Program spusten bez parametru\n");
    }

    strcpy("-", adresa);

    int i = 0;

    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, %d\n", argc, i);
        if(strcmp("-h", argv[i]) == 0)
        {
            printf("Help");
            exit(0);
        }
        else if(strcmp("-a", argv[i]) == 0)
        {
            if(argc > (i + 1))
            {
                if(strlen(argv[i + 1]) < 255)
                {
                    //memset(adresa, '\0', sizeof(adresa));
                    strcpy(argv[i + 1], adresa);
                    printf("Zadana adresa %s\n", adresa);

                    i++;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Adresa je prilis dlouha (> 255)\n");
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Parametry jsou ve spatnem tvaru\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Parametry jsou ve spatnem tvaru\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}



int main(int argv, char **argc)
{
    checkParameters(argv, argc);

    int optval;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;//, incoming_addr;

    /* create socket */
    sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (sock < 0)
    {
        err("socket()");
    }

    /* set reusable flag */
    optval = 1;
    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof(optval));

    /* prepare inet address */
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    if(strcmp(adresa, "-") == 0)
    {
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); /* listen on all interfaces */        
    }
    else
    {
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(adresa); /* listen on all interfaces */
    }


    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        err("bind");
    }

    for(;;)
    {

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `strcpy("-", adresa)` you cannot copy to a string literal pointer. Did you mean `strcpy(adresa, "-")` ?

Comment: Again, in `strcpy(argv[i + 1], adresa);` it is unwise (perhaps not forbidden) to overwrite the argument passed to `main`.

Comment: Man, that's exactly my problem! I didn't see, thanks a lot!
And one more question, do you know about sockets? Just wanted to know, if in later `if` statement I can just use `htonl(adresa)` or if I should do it with another way

Comment: Please ask about sockets in another question.

Comment: Okey, I will create new question, thanks again.